# multiple datepicker in a page (php)

Tags: php

im trying to use two date picker in a page. it seems to worked fine but after  clicked on the submit button the date entered is not the same as the choosen date. both of the date inserted to the database is 01-01-1970.

how can i fix this?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Date Issued</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="dateIssuedpc" name="dateissued" required class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Date Issued"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Date Expired</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="dateExpiredpc" name="dateexpired" required class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Date Expired" />
    </div>
</div>



<script>
$( function() {
$( "#dateIssuedpc").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
});
$( "#dateExpiredpc" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
  });
  } );
 </script>
```

Comment: try to do `print_r($_REQUEST)` before you save the information into the db and see if it prints correctly

Comment: Check your field type in the database.

Comment: You need to covert date format before store into database. Default DB date format was YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s. OR your can set  dateFormat: "Full Year- Leading Zero month- Leading zero day" into datepicker,

Comment: Add your PHP insert code also with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if field data type in database is datetime then

```
$dateexpired = $_POST['dateexpired'];
$new_dateexpired = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($dateexpired));
$dateissued = $_POST['dateissued'];
$new_dateissued = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($dateissued));
```

if field data type is date then

```
$dateexpired = $_POST['dateexpired'];
$new_dateexpired = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dateexpired));
$dateissued = $_POST['dateissued'];
$new_dateissued = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dateissued));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not datepicker problem, rather problem is with PHP code.

Mysql date format is always `YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS`

So while inserting data to mysql table, you have to convert the format for mysql

Ex:

```
$postDate = $_POST['date'];// just collect value from post fields.
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($postDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your date properly. First of all change format from `dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",` to `*dateFormat: "dd-mm-yyyy",*` to better recognise year.

After that from php side you something like this

```
$dateissued = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['dateissued']) ); //MySql date format
```